# Is it safe to use Select Top and Delete Top in sequence?

Tags: t-sql

I often write T-SQL loops that look like this in upgrade scripts:

```
While Exists (Select * From #MyTable)
    Begin
    Declare @ID int, @Word nvarchar(max)
    Select Top 1 @ID=ID, @Word=[Word] From #MyTable
    -- Do something --
    Delete #MyTable Where ID=@ID
    End
```

Works a treat but I noticed the new Delete Top function which would be useful when #MyTable is just a list of strings. In this case, would this work:

```
While Exists (Select * From #MyTable)
    Begin
    Declare @Word nvarchar(max)
    Select Top 1 @Word=[Word] From #MyTable
    -- Do something --
    Delete Top(1) #MyTable
    End
```

Well yes, it works in my test script but is this safe? Will Select Top 1 and Delete Top(1) always refer to the same record or is Top a little more vague.

Thanks, Rob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your second example is not safe.

If you are going to use "SELECT TOP ..." (and you care about the order in which the rows are selected) you should really use an "ORDER BY" to explicitly specify the order. You MIGHT get the order you want without "ORDER BY", but SQL Server makes no guarantees about the order of returned rows when ORDER BY is not used.

In the case of "DELETE TOP ..", you can't add an "ORDER BY", so you should use a WHERE clause which uniquely identifies the row(s) to be deleted, as you have done in your first example.

Comment: Thank for this, I kind of suspected this was the case.

Answer (score 2):

If you often write loops either you are doing something wrong or your database needs a redesign or you are inserting large batches of data that need to run in batches of 1000 records or so. I'll bet almost everything you are doing could be done in a set-based fashion and improve performance tremendously. I can't show you how without knowing what kind of thing happens inteh do somthing, but likely it can be made set-based by using a case startement.

Comment: +1, loops+database=slow.  however, the OP is not using a cursor!

Comment: And I never said he was. But there is a good chance that what he is doing can be done in a set-based fashion.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified "I often write loops in upgrade scripts"... would never do anything like that in the actual application itself!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OUTPUT statement in this case, you don't need the ORDER BY using OUTPUT like this:

```
DELETE #Origin_table
OUTPUT deleted.* INTO #Loop_Work
```

Full example:

```
--DROP TABLE #Origin_table, #Loop_Work

CREATE TABLE #Origin_table (I INT IDENTITY, N VARCHAR(100))
INSERT #Origin_table VALUES
      ('Test A'), ('Test B'), ('Test C')
    , ('Test D'), ('Test E'), ('Test F')
    , ('Test G'), ('Test H'), ('Test I')


CREATE TABLE #Loop_Work (I INT, N VARCHAR(100))

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #Origin_table) BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE #Loop_Work           --> Clear faster our table for loop

    DELETE TOP (3) #Origin_table        --> Delete top records
    OUTPUT deleted.* INTO #Loop_Work    --> Use the same records as OUTPUT and insert into the #Loop_Work
                                        --> The OUTPUT statement works similar as a trigger --> It's safe!

    SELECT * FROM #Loop_Work            --> Do what you need
END
```

If you want to order then use a [CTE (Common Table Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in the DELETE:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE #Loop_Work

;WITH To_Delete AS ( --Remember the semicolon
    SELECT TOP 3 *
    FROM #Origin_table
        ORDER BY I DESC
    )
DELETE To_Delete --And use the CTE
OUTPUT deleted.* INTO #Loop_Work
```